# How can I use python to determine if a USB camera, mic, and speaker are selectable on Linux, Mac, and Windows?

Tags: python, audio, camera, usb, pyusb

**Goal:** I am looking for a cross-platform solution to determine if the camera, mic, and speaker are enumerated and selectable. If the camera fails to enumerate while the mic and speaker do enumerate, I would like to throw an error that the camera failed to Enumerate. I am also looking for all the other permutations of a failed enumeration while keeping in mind the knowledge from one could be extracted into the other tests.

**Hardware:** Think of it as a phone that is plugged in via USB. The phone as mic, speaker, and camera support.

**Tried:** I have looked into single-platform solutions such as the following for Mac:

- `system_profiler SPCameraDataType | grep -i <device_string>`
- `system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep -i <device_string>`

**Issue:** This is exactly what I am looking for but does not scale directly to Linux and Windows

**Tried:** I have also looked into the Python `USB` library in an attempt to find a multi-platform solution:
`devices = usb.core.find(idVendor=<myVenderID>)`

**Issue:** It seems to show the USB config file sent when a USB device is plugged in, not listing selectable endpoints. This could lead to false positives because it would not indicate a partial failure (Only audio enumeration, not video).